# How to log method calls on targets marked with an attribute?

Tags: c#

Is it possible to inject Loggin behaviour to the marked classes or/and methods like this:

```
Log("Method {0} started",GetMethodNameTroughReflection)
Call method body
Log("Method {0} Finished",GetMethodNameTroughReflection)
```

I want to create my own Attribute class, which will realize loging behaviour for method call.

I want to describe login behaviour in the app.config file, thoug it can be disabled by a setting in config.

How to do it right? Maybe there is created solution for tasks like this one?

Comment: You might wanna check [PostSharp](http://www.sharpcrafters.com/) or an [IoC framework](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inversion_of_control) and read about [aspect oriented programming](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/242177/what-is-aspect-oriented-programming).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This can be done using aspect-oriented programming (AOP). Have a look at **[PostSharp](http://www.sharpcrafters.com/)**. See the sample for tracing here:

> **[Non-Invasive Tracing & Logging](http://doc.postsharp.net/logging)**

Answer (score 0):

Search for 'aspect oriented programming' - Logging is a canonical example. for instance [this link](http://www.shanekercheval.com/?p=41) accomplishes it using PostSharp