# Using attributes to start function

Tags: c#, attributes, stopwatch

I have a function that uses a stopwatch instance and measure time of any method put inside. now, I have to start and stop that for every method. I want to so this now using attribute. I want to place just an attribute over every method which automatically starts and stops my function which measures the time.

The code of function:

```
 [DataContract]
[Serializable]

public class AppTrace:BaseModel<AppTrace>
{
    [DataMember]
    public string Comment;
    [DataMember]
    public string MethodName;
    [DataMember]
    public DateTime StartTimeStamp;
    [DataMember]
    public int Duration;
    [DataMember]
    public int UserObjectId;
    [DataMember]
    public string MachineName;
    [DataMember]
    public int ToolId;
    private System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch stpWatch;

public AppTrace(string comment,string methodName,int userObjectId ,string machineName = "",int? toolId=null)

    {
        MethodName = methodName;
        UserObjectId = userObjectId;
        StartTimeStamp = DateTime.UtcNow;
        Comment = comment;
        MachineName = machineName;

        stpWatch = new System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch();
        stpWatch.Start();
    }

    public AppTrace()
    {
    }

    public void CloseTrace()
    {
        this.stpWatch.Stop();
        Duration=Convert.ToInt32( this.stpWatch.ElapsedMilliseconds);
    }
```

Comment: Can you please include the code you have tried in the question.

Comment: now instead of calling AppTrace and Close trace everytime i want to use a function, can i do the decoration with just an attrubute that automatically starts and stops this.

Answer (score 0):

That probably won't work with only the .NET Framework. [Aspect oriented programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aspect-oriented_programming) is implemented by various third party providers, [Postsharp](https://www.postsharp.net/) probably being the most used.

You can implement your own attributes, but without an [AOP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/242177/what-is-aspect-oriented-programming) framework, they will not execute any code for you. They are just metadata that you can query with reflection.

Comment: Is there any way to do this except Aop. i don't want to use third party library.

Comment: If you have a unified caller (for example a kind of factory calling all your methods) then that could query the attributes. But if your caller is *anybody* then no, there is no way to use attributes to execute code without third party AOP tools.

Answer (score 0):

Another way to solve this, would be something like :

```
protected void StopwatchThis(Action func)
        {
            //some code
            func.Invoke();
            //more code
        }
```

So if you are doing some optimization and want to test the run time, you could basicly just delegate your methods to this function and get the output.

question bit too broad