# How to invoke a function on calling other static function?

Tags: php

How can I invoke a function automatically when any static function is called once.

```
class A{
    private static $val;
    public static function X(){
        return static::$val;
    }
}

class B extend A
{    

}
```

Is it possible if I call `B::X();` then a function can set the value of `$val` of parent class. This has to be done without creating a instance of `class B`.

I wanted to do this automatically. something like what construct does. Before any static method is called I want to invoke a function automatically

Comment: Tell us about X problem, not about Y.

Comment: Is there any way to initialize the value $val from class B without actually creating a instance of B.

Answer (score 0):

> Is it possible if I call B::X(); then a function can set the value of
>   $val of parent class. This has to be done without creating a instance
>   of class B

Try this:

```
class A {
    protected static $val;
    public static function X(){
        return static::$val;
    }
}

class B extends A
{
    public static function X(){
        static::$val = 123;
        return parent::X();
    }
}

echo B::X();
```

You have to

- Replace `private static $val;` with `protected static $val;` to make property visible in class `B`
- You have to use `extends` instead of `extend`
- You can use `parent::` to call a method of parent class (In your case class `A`)

Comment: I'm sorry, I guess I wasn't able to convey what exactly I wanted. I wanted to do this automatically. something like what construct does. Before any static method is called I want to invoke a function automatically.

Comment: Maybe you should take a look at [aspect-oriented programming](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/242177/what-is-aspect-oriented-programming).