# Template method - enforce method to call another method

Tags: c#, oop

Let's assume we have the following class:

```
public class Employee
{
  public string Name { get; private set; } 
  public string Team { get; private set; }

  public Employee(string name, string team)
  {
    this.Name = name;
    this.Team = team;
  }

  public void UpdateName(string newName, string updatedBy)
  {
    this.Name = newName;

    this.Update(updatedBy);
  }

  public void UpdateTeam(string newTeam, string updatedBy)
  {
    this.Team = newTeam;

    this.Update(updatedBy);
  }

  private void Update(string updatedBy)
  {
    // and do something with updatedBy
  }
}
```

Is there a better way in C# I can enforce a method (e.g. `UpdateTeam` to call `Update` method and pass it a string parameter - e.g. `updatedBy`)?

Of course there is no such syntax, but just to illustrate what I mean:

```
public class Employee
{
  // ...

  public void UpdateTeam(string newTeam, string updatedBy) : Update(updatedBy)
  {
    this.Team = newTeam;
  }

  private void Update(string updatedBy)
  {
    // and do something with updatedBy
  }
}
```

Edit: I know about the 'Template' pattern, it's NOT what I need.

Comment: Not declaratively - you can verify that you get the right _results_ with unit tests but there is not a mechanism to enforce a specific _implementation_.

Comment: You could look into [Aspect-oriented programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aspect-oriented_programming) with a tool like Postsharp.

Answer (score 1):

I believe that models should be lightweight and there is no place for business logic inside model classes. You should consider extracting business logic in a separate class. This concept may help:

```
public class UpdateNameCommand : ICommand<UpdateNameContext>
{
    public void Execute(UpdateNameContext context)
    {
        UpdateEmployeeName(context.NewName);
        UpdateTeam(context.UpdatedBy);
    }

    private void UpdateEmployeeName(string name)
    {
        // ...
    }

    private void UpdateTeam(string updatedBy)
    {
        // ...
    }
}

public interface ICommand<TContext>
{
    void Execute(TContext context);
}
```

Where command context is a simple class that is responsible to pass data to the command and (if needed) receive results after command execution.

It not necessarily should be a command but any separate class that is responsible for business case. And other programmers should use it to perform this specific action. This class (or method) should encapsulate necessary logic and exposes simple interface for calling from the outside.

Good reading about [SOLID principles](http://www.codemag.com/article/1001061). The described approach covers at least 2 principles and maybe more depending on your application needs:

> S - Single responsibility
>   O - Open/Closed principle

Comment: Thanks for your response. But I feel that the business logic related to that object, belongs exactly in the object, as in my example. Isn't that the core principle of the Object-Oriented Programming? I don't think I violate the 'S', because the exposed methods still serve the same responsibility - maintaining the Employee object. If I am to extract this logic into a Command/Handler pattern, we are effectively moving from OOP (rich model), to Procedural programming (anemic model).

Comment: @HristoYankov it's your opinion and I respect it. I am just a believer that models should be lightweight. I also prefer to keep business logic separate from models. I think in a real world applications there will be a lot of business logic related to model and if you put all of it in a single class, it will be too much for `single responsibility`. Even now you have UpdateTeam method that actually belongs to a Team class and not Employee. Very controversial and it's just my opinion.

Comment: Sorry, I named it badly. It has nothing to do with managing another object (i.e. Team). Should have called it 'Age' or something. Regardless, I like your command approach.

Comment: @HristoYankov thank you. And I am not criticizing your approach. Everyone has preferences. Hope you will fine a good way to workaround your problem. Martin suggested AOP, it might help you.

Answer (score 0):

Add code to your setter of `Name` and `Team` that it will set an internal property and then call `Update`.

`UpdatedBy` should be in another class. Your now mixing 2 responsibilities into one class.

Comment: @DStanley Added comment that it should be not into this class

Answer (score 0):

No, there is no better way than what you already suggested. :)

Of course there are some other ways to do it (setting a property instead of calling a method, perhaps even calling an event, but in all cases you need add that call manually.)

You might want to consider AOP. AOP lets you define a special attribute which can call a method before or after your public method is called. Of course you still have to add that attribute manually.

For more information about AOP, take a look at: https://www.postsharp.net/

Comment: Thanks for your response, adding the attribute manually is not an issue.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could try to use Aspect-Oriented Programming. It seems like AOP can help you. One of definition would be:

> An aspect is a common feature that's typically scattered across
>   methods, classes, object hierarchies, or even entire object models. It
>   is behavior that looks and smells like it should have structure, but
>   you can't find a way to express this structure in code with
>   traditional object-oriented techniques.

So, you need to do extra job by changing name or team. That "extra job" should not be mixed with your code, because of cleanness of you design.

There is one very nice post here:
[What is aspect-oriented programming?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/242177/what-is-aspect-oriented-programming)